# What is best practice for sending html special characters to server and back?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, special-characters, html-entities

What is the best practice for sending possible html/javascript/code to server and then receiving it?

I have a chat where users should be able to send code i.e. html. Should I send this html and other text as plain text or should I change the <> and some other chracters into html entities before saving it to database?

I was thinking of sending and saving plain text and then converting chracters to html entities using JavaScript regex, when displaying it to a user.

What is the best practice? I also have to use this data in angular.js where plain text is easier to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always submit and store the original input. Storing the input already prepared for being output on a special device or software (i.e., a HTML interpreter in your case) makes it difficult to use the data for other purposes. This might be for example a chat app for mobile devices which you might add later.